# How can I add drawerLayout and not to damage existed LinerLayout style?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I began doing a project without DrawableLayout. I am using mostly LinearLayout. I want to add drawer navigation android, and as I know, I need DrawableLayout. 
How can I add this, and not damage everything I have now?

Comment: It might help if you include some code snippets so that others can point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Well don't be afraid. It's not so difficult. Just follow the following steps to get it:-

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark">

<!-- put you linear layout here --!>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        android:id="@+id/nv">

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**Navigation Header:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">
  <ImageView
      android:layout_width="180dp"
      android:layout_height="130dp"
      android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
      android:background="@drawable/ic_android_black_24dp"/>

</LinearLayout>

**Create a menu for the navigation drawer**
Right-click the res folder →Select new →Android resource file →Choose ‘menu’ under the resource type drop-down list.
Name the file as ‘navigation_menu.xml’ and copy-paste the following code into the file.

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@+id/account"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_portrait_black_24dp"
        android:title="My Account"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_brightness_high_black_24dp"
        android:title="Settings"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/mycart"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_local_grocery_store_black_24dp"
        android:title="My Cart"/>

</menu>
```

** Lastly, in you activity:** <br>
In this last and final step, we will write Java code in the MainActivity.java file.

```
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DrawerLayout dl;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle t;
    private NavigationView nv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        dl = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
        t = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, dl,R.string.Open, R.string.Close);

        dl.addDrawerListener(t);
        t.syncState();

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        nv = (NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.nv);
        nv.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                int id = item.getItemId();
                switch(id)
                {
                    case R.id.account:
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "My Account",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();break;
                    case R.id.settings:
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Settings",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();break;
                    case R.id.mycart:
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "My Cart",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();break;
                    default:
                        return true;
                }


                return true;

            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if(t.onOptionsItemSelected(item))
            return true;

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}`
```

Comment: Thanks very much! I madeit with help of your code, and some internet source. It works, it launches... But I cant see my Toolbar with buttons... 
But I f i click on the place where buttons supposed to be, they do action.

Comment: You can share your project if you want to, I will take a look if you want. But if you were helped, please make my answer correct and give me an up vote if possible. :)